# Use a safe navegation operator and then compare result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I really don't know how to put a clear title for what I am trying to do.

I am working with RoR and in a controller I have this statement:

```rb
recipe.cover_image.attach(data: params[:recipe][:cover_image]) if params[:recipe][:cover_image] && params[:recipe][:cover_image].length > 255
```

So I was trying to use the safe navigation operator for doing it a bit more compact and easy to read, something like this:

```rb
recipe.cover_image.attach(data: params[:recipe][:cover_image]) if params[:recipe][:cover_image]&.length > 255
```

But It doesn't work. I got this:

```
undefined method `\u003e' for nil:NilClass
```

The problem is that when is nil, it does something like: nil > 255 ?

Is there a way to do this? Another action after the safe navigation operator?

Comment: `nil.to_i` is `0`

Comment: @Stefan thanks you! This solve in a way the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can add `.to_i` to the end of `.length` to ensure you're comparing like types.  E.g.

```
recipe.cover_image.attach(data: params[:recipe][:cover_image]) if params[:recipe][:cover_image]&.length.to_i > 255
```

The reason you're getting that error is that `NilClass` does not have a method called `>`.  However, `NilClass` does have a `.to_i` method, which always returns `0`.  Since `>` is a method on `Integer` and `0` is an `Integer`, the comparison will *just work*.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that ``\u003e'` was `>` itself. So now I understand better the problem and for this case it works because the comparison is grater than. But what about less than? I mean, if this is nil I don't want to compare it, I want to return the false to 'if' to skip the statement like it was working in the first sentence I wrote in the problem. Do you understand me? Well, still you resolve my problem.

Comment: @Andrés `<` and `>` are just method calls so you could technically safe navigate around them too e.g. `params[:recipe][:cover_image]&.length&.<(255)`. That being said with additional context there might be better more idiomatic ways to solve this

Comment: @engineersmnky I understand now, I was looking for that. Thank you!